# Asmx file is not returning XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asmx

I am practising with ASMX web services, where I encounter this problem. I have a class file `Employee.cs` which consists of three fields **Id, Name, Salary**.

**My Service Code :**

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public string GetEmlpoyees() {
   Employee emps = new Employee[]{
      new Employee ()
      {
         // data...
      }
   };
   return emps;
}
```

Here it returns an error red marking the instance **emps** that **cannot implicitly convert type ProjectName.Employee[] to string**

I think it might be a minor issue but as i am new to web service.....it's getting on my nerves......How to get rid of this issue....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the public function **GetEmlpoyees** says you are going to return a **string**, but instead you are returning **emps** which is an array of **Employee[]**

The compiler is expecting you to return the type you declare in the functions signature, so both types should match.

You need to change the return type to **Employee[]** like this:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public Employee[] GetEmlpoyees() {
   Employee emps = new Employee[]{
      new Employee ()
      {
         // data...
      }
   };
   return emps;
}
```